# SSRS Expression to get data parameter to start on specified month for current year?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a date parameter that I want to set to be set for the 1st of the most recent October, for now it would be '10/01/2021'.

I have tried this expression:

```
="10/01/" & IIf(Month(Today()) < 10, Year(Today()), DateAdd("yyyy",-1,YEAR(Today())))
```

Which throws this error: Argument 'DateValue' cannot be converted to type 'Date'.
Even besides error, not sure if the logic is right.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression

```
=DateSerial(Year(Today()), 10, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=DateSerial(
           IIF(Month(today()) >=10 , Year(Today()), Year(Today()) - 1)
           , 10
           , 1)
```